# Is that possible to transfer file from Raspberry PI to PC through LAN?

Tags: wireless, data-transfer

I plan to transfer file on PI to my MAC just through LAN. For example, both of them connect with the same router (which do not connect with Internet). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you are looking for a way without installing any additional sw, then `scp` is probably the easiest way to do it. On your Mac type

```
scp rpi_user@rpi_ip_addres:/full_path_to_file /full_path_on_your_mac
```

paths might be also relative (to your home in rpi, to current dir on mac)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The easiest way to transfer files is with an SFTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1). Install that on the computer you want to transfer the files to. Start the software, then put in the IP address of your pi, your username, and enter the account password when prompted. You should see a list of files in the home directory (e.g. /home/pi) which you can then navigate and download/upload to, just like FTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. As @Fred indicated, `ftp` is one possibility.

You can also use `ssh` to transfer files from the terminal prompt. (`OS X` has `ssh` installed).

You could install `netatalk` on the Pi which lets you use Finder to access the Pi. Connect with `afp://raspberrypi.local` (or the `IP` address).